# How to manually retrieve form data on Create POST request in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, forms, model-binding

I have a Create action as part of my controller which binds data to a class called Bar. My issue is that I have a setup with many to many related categories that I can't work out in Entity Framework Core. The deadline for this school project is approaching soon, so for now I'm looking for a way to manually bind my form fields to the model and related objects.

My controller runs the following action on the POST request

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Name,Address,CocktailType,Bartype,NightclubType,Price,Categories")] Bar bar)
```

What I want to achieve is to have access to fields from the form which are not part of the Bar model and map them manually. How would I access these fields?

Basically i wan't to be able to do something like the following:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Name,Address,CocktailType,Bartype,NightclubType,Price,Categories")] Bar bar)
    {
        bar.AddCategory({ Name:  FormFields.NameOfField, CategoryId: FormFields.NameOfOtherField });
```

Comment: Use viewmodels?

Comment: A little more explanation would be helpful. If i knew how viewmodels could solve this, i would have done it already.

Comment: You decide what you want in models, create view model for it, then create form in view, then in the action you can receive that view model map the essential parts of it to the bars and rest fields can be used to achieve what you want.